# Multiple string match without using every function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently i am doing multiple string match in javascript, i know most of us are familiar with javascript `every` method, as a result it provides `true` or `false`. Is there any other way in performance wise better than this.

```
'javascript code'.split(' ').every(val => 'you should code in javascript'.includes(val));
```

Actual string length of mine is very big, it becomes performance bottleneck when i using this js `every` method.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please provide some context to the problem.

Comment: Every is O(n). Which string is very big the first one or the one you are searching is in

Comment: both of them are very big @TusharShahi

Comment: Is there any other way using regex, because there are so much of iterations are happening with this method i am using.

Comment: You can convert it to `Set` and then check for subset or superset accordingly. [Implementing basic set operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#implementing_basic_set_operations)

Comment: Is your goal to see if a string is a substring of another? This will return true if `"code javascript"` was your input, is that expected?

Comment: `Is your goal to see if a string is a substring of another?` yes. but in this method performace is little low.

Comment: @htoniv if you want to check if it's a substring, then why have you not done `'hello this is my javascript code'.includes('javascript code')`?

Comment: it may be this also `hello this is javascript my code`, that's why i splitting and searching.

Comment: On that case, you *aren't* checking for a subtsring. That's why Nick Parsons asked for clarification. The goal wasn't clear to me, either.

Comment: Oh shit i understood now i changed the string, now it is clear?

Comment: @Arvind oh yeah i will try with `Set`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the set of words is a subset of the larger set of words..

```
const needles = 'javascript code'.split(' ');
const haystack = 'you should code in javascript'.split(' ');

const is_subSet = (a, b) => {
  const setA = new Set(a), setB = new Set(b);
  return [...setA].every(v => setB.has(v));
};

is_subSet(needles, haystack);
```